A sequence question, relating the Jacobsthal to the Fibonacci sequence.
I am stuck on a problem I have been working on and would like some advice. I found that, given the initial $J_0=0,J_1=1$ for the Jacobsthal numbers and $F_0=0,F_1=1$ for the Fibonnaci numbers, the nth Jacobsthal number $J_n=F_n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(J_iF_{n-1-i})$ for $n\geq2$. However, I can't find a way to prove this, by relating this to the closed form expressions $J_n=\frac{1}{3}(2^n-(-1)^n)$ and $F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n)$. I am not looking for a solution, but advice.

did you consider taking the generating functions and multiplying them?

You can use induction to show.

First
$$ F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n, F_0=0, F_1=1, J_{n+2}=J_{n+1}+2J_n, J_0=0, J_1=1. $$
When $n=2$, $J_n=J_2=J_1+2J_0=1$ and
$$ F_n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}J_iF_{n-1-i}=F_2+J_0F_1=F_2=F_1+F_0=1 $$
and hence $J_n=F_n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}J_iF_{n-1-i}$ holds for $n=2$.
Suppose when $n=k-1,n=k$, the identity holds; namely
$$J_{k-1}=F_{k-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-3}J_iF_{k-2-i}, J_k=F_k+\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}J_iF_{k-1-i}$$
Now
$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&F_{k+1}+\sum_{i=0}^{(k+1)-2}J_iF_{(k+1)-1-i}\\
&=&F_{k}+F_{k-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}J_iF_{k-i}=F_{k}+F_{k-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}J_iF_{k-i}+J_{k-1}F_{1}\\
&=&F_{k}+F_{k-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}J_i(F_{k-i-1}+F_{k-i-2})+J_{k-1}\\
&=&F_{k}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}J_iF_{k-i-1}+F_{k-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}J_iF_{k-i-2}+J_{k-1}\\
&=&F_{k}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}J_iF_{k-i-1}+F_{k-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-3}J_iF_{k-i-2}+J_{k-1}\\
&=&J_k+2J_{k-1}=J_{k+1}.
\end{eqnarray}$$
Namely when $n=k+1$, the identity holds. By Induction, the identity holds for each $n\ge 2$.
